# How to setup django signals in django project which has multiple apps in it?

Tags: python, django, notifications, signals, django-signals

Tree structure of my project

```
    ├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── signals.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── app2
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── config.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── migrations
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── signals.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── dummy
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── templates
    ├── home_page.html
    └── index.html
```

i have tried few things to setup django signals like in `app1-->__init__.py` inserted this `default_app_config = "apps.app1.config.App1Config"`
and in `config.py` file inserted this code `app1-->config.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "app1"

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

and in `app1--> signals.py` file inserted this code to check if signals are working or not

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Demo

@receiver(post_save, sender=Demo)
def your_signal_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print("Created")
    else:
        print("Created")
```

but its not working

i want to use django signals for project at work which has notifications app in project which handle all the notifications of project from different apps but i will use celery with django signals

Comment: What is not working? How do you try to "trigger" the signal.

Comment: from admin pannel i created a new entry in demo model but there was nothing on terminal

Comment: on the one where you run `runserver`? Can you share the `admin.py` and the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "apps.app1",
    "apps.app2",
]

Comment: and in admin.py file i just register the model Demo like

admin.site.register(Demo)

Comment: what if you add a `print(..)` before the `@receiver` to just test if the module has been loaded.

Comment: yeah i tested it with couple of ways . so in short its loaded

Answer (score 0):

I would [recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) renaming the `app1/config.py` to `app1/apps.py`.

Why? [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) configures an application in AppConfig subclass of apps.py module

and in `app1->apps.py` file insert this code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "app1"

    def ready(self):
        import app1.signals
```

Similarly you can do this in `app2` as well.

Comment: thats what config file is doing RN.

Comment: There is no reference to config.py file in Django documentation so I thought that might be the issue. Try renaming it to apps.py, and tell if the issue still persists.